# How GPS works in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, gps

I am using a iPhone 3g. I am in India(I got it in India). I just tried to check my location using the Google Maps. My location was spotted when I had sim in my phone.  But when I took out the SIM from iPhone, I did not get my location. I tried the same with the Locate me Sample Application . So can someone  explain how GPS works in iPhone, and how to fix my problem(to get my location when there is no SIM).

Thanks and Regards,
krishnan

Comment: You need to accept some of your answers, or you'll risk the chance that people may not even try to help you. To accept an answer, click the ✔ under the answer you like the most, or that you feel helped you. ⎷ ✔ ⎷ ✔

Comment: Hi Emil. I am sorry for that. I did not know this option. Thats why the problem. Thanks for your polite suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nolim suggested, I tried checking in outdoors and it worked. If you are checking within your office space or home, get out of it completely and go to a open space and check there. It should work, irrespective of whether you have SIM or not.( Usually when you have SIM, it A-GPS would work).If it is not working immediately, wait for some time, for around 2-3 minutes and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone uses AGPS, or Assisted Global Positioning System.
That means that the iPhone uses both GPS and internet information to get your location. If you are not connected to a WiFi network or your phone doesn't have a SIM-card in it, it won't be able to locate you.

You can't get the location of an iPhone if you have no internet, so I suggest you check wether the phone is connected to any type of internet, and show a warning if it isn't.
But the GPS will still work if you are connected to a WiFi Hotspot.

Comment: Hi Emil,
I am connected to a wi-fi Hotspot in my office Space. but even then I don't get my current Location....

Comment: I think the WiFi Hotspot you use must be registered with the service that Apple uses to get the location.

Comment: Go to http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/submit_ap.php and add the wifi hotspot and then wait

Comment: Hi Plumenator/Emil,

I think the Wifi must be registered with some Server to get them detected. I found a link which many had suggested. http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/FindMyAP.php. Does it mean that when I travel to a place, where there is no signal, I will not be able to find my location.

Comment: I did not try this option, Nolim1t.

Comment: @Krishnan: Yes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I use Iphone 4S. In my opinion: Without a sim card, GPS function will not work. Likewise, without connection to a cellular signal, GPS function will not work. (The detail about data plan or not is irrelevant.)

In my opinion : the Iphone has AGPS chipset, but has NO GPS receiver (like that of a regular Garmin).

Answer (score 0):

I know the iPhone uses assisted GPS: it first looks for the rough location by cell tower, knows the GPS satellites to expect for that rough location, and then finds a more precise location. Maybe when the first step fails (no SIM means no cell tower fix), the API's do not work?

Comment: Hi Henno,

thanks For your response. The reason you specify may be true reason. I am hoping it would work.

Comment: Try going outdoors or holding your iPhone near the window where it can see the sky. You may be able to get a GPS fix (it will take a while to lock on)

Comment: Nolim1t , I tried the same you have specified. It worked like a charm. Thanks Nolim1t

Comment: Hi Friends(Emil, NOlim1t, Plumentaor), Thanks all for your time. The only problem I facing is like, The service does not work (if sim is removed), when  I am inside my office. When I take my phone  outside of my office, it works . Any way thanks all.

Comment: The iPhone uses many things, including cell ID and WiFi SSID. It communicates these to a server, which returns an estimated location and (possibly) a list of nearby satellites.

I'm pretty sure the GPS also works standalone, but you need much stronger signal; non-assisted GPS generally doesn't work indoors.